# Why would a dragon prefer to pilot a fighter plane?

Tags: technology, weapons, fantasy-races, aircraft

In my medieval-fantasy world, there’s a secret civilization with modern technology.

A “powerful” dragon accidentally came across them and they became good allies. The dragon was introduced to the concept of aircraft and it wasn’t long until she decided to ride one.
The dragon shrunk into a more humanoid form, with the appropriate limbs and digits.

The dragon loved to fly in a fighter plane, so much so that she refuses to fly under her own power as much as before.

Why would this be so?

Comment: I can't imagine she would... that's like saying that, having discovered cars, you decided to never walk again. There may be a certain aspect of laziness, and wanting to fly a jet *as often as possible* is certainly plausible, but I suspect she'd also sometimes want the tactile experience of unassisted flight, and I doubt she would *refuse* to fly under her own power ever again. (Unless we're talking about contextual refusal only, i.e. won't fly *for military purposes* under her own power.)

Comment: Calvin and Hobbes: Dinosaurs flying F-14's.....https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/t-rex-jet

Comment: +1 For a mental image that made me laugh out loud

Comment: There's an anime on netflix right now that's all about Dragons that pretend to be F15s and such. https://www.netflix.com/title/80241960

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can think of four* reasons why the dragon would want to pilot a fighter plane rather than fly in its dragon form, with the three reasons leading to the most important fourth one.

---

**Novelty**

One reason would be similar to why people watch movies or play games; to do something novel that they normally cannot do. Rather than flying with their own body, they can control the plane to do maneuvers, like a sort of game.

---

**Aerodynamics, Speed, Stamina**

Apart from that, a dragon’s normal flying form is probably the last thing anyone would think of when considering aerodynamics. A dragon, assuming without the use of any magics, would probably fly no faster than a bird when in the air. To fly quickly at a reasonable speed would also quickly consume the dragon’s stamina or magic as well.

Compare that to a fighter plane, which can easily hit subsonic or supersonic speeds, and consumes no stamina to run, only the measliest of fossil fuels. It would also be much more agile and potentially deadly, being able to fire missiles rather than using up the dragon’s magic powers.

Not to mention, in the event of emergencies, the dragon still has its dragon form as backup, with a full tank of stamina and magic.

---

**Organic vs Mass-Produced**

Finally, considering the existence of fighter planes in such an age, a dragon in dragon form would be nothing more than a sitting duck. Due to its slow speed, it would practically be a stationary target for fighter planes. Even if it has magic, if it is swarmed by fifty or five hundred fighter planes it would probably eventually run out of magic and be forced into a sorry state.

Even though the secret civilization is the only one possessing such a technology, who knows if that will be so in the future? By forming an alliance, the dragon gets to try out the new technology and find its weaknesses, giving itself an advantage should other civilization adopt similar technologies.

This problem mainly exists because the dragon is a single, organic entity, meaning it has a limited amount of magic and stamina. The fighter plane *is the culmination of the efforts of countless human beings*, and can be *mass produced*. As a single organic entity, the dragon cannot withstand the might of an entire civilization, and thus, needs to make use of their efforts to improve its own efficiency.

---

**King of the Skies**

*Inspired by the discussion in the comments*

The most important reason, since the dragon itself has probably considered the prior three. Assuming the dragon is extremely powerful, and capable of magic (due to shape-shifting), giving it a fighter plane would be the equivalent of making it the King of the Skies. In dragon form, there are weaknesses that allow enough enemies to swarm it and tire it out, but what if that same dragon was in a fighter plane?

Assuming a dragon, to fly, would need to use magic to reduce drag, function as an air-brake, and alter its ability to withstand high-G turns and maneuvers, can't these things be applied to the fighter plane too? You would then have a fighter plane that is much quicker than its peers, capable of doing inhuman maneuvers mid-air, and piloted by a dragon with faster/better/stronger reflexes and an insane amount of aerial combat experience. Even if they sent hundreds of fighter planes to go after such an opponent, would anyone be capable of shooting down or even catching up to such a fighter plane?

Using the human technology would allow the dragon to remain the king of the skies, no matter how much human technologies progress.

---

**Summary**

In conclusion, the fighter plane is probably novel to the dragon, and also allows it to fly faster, save energy, and be competitive in a tough job market. By making use of the highly advanced fighter plane, with its experience and magic, the dragon would remain the dominator of the skies.

Comment: This is a case of dragon sharting fire out of its rear vs a dragon shooting it out of its mouth.

Comment: @Inthenameofthestory the problem is air resistance, even if the dragon is sharting fire out of it’s rear, the faster it goes, the more air resistance there is (increasing exponentially). This means the faster it goes, the amount of energy it consumes goes up massively. At a certain point, probably the sonic barrier, the energy needed would completely drain the dragon. Besides, just lighting a fire doesn’t make something move. A fighter jet’s fire is actually used to push out fuel to propel it, a dragon has no such fuel to push, even if it lights a fire behind it.

Comment: The dragon shooting fire out it's rear will eventually evolve delta wings and resemble an F-16...

Comment: @Thucydides that is totally absurd. I love it XD. The dragon would tuck in its neck, arms, and wings and transform into a fighter jet

Comment: At least the dragon isn't transforming into a truck..... ;-)

Comment: @Thucydides No, that’s the Sphinxes’ job ;-)

Comment: Ah, the beautiful scenes of dragons being introduced to modern warfare in Gate. Though a dragon would be more agile then a fighter.  And +1 just for this comment thread.

Comment: @JanDorniak it would probably take some magic to go against momentum, and reduce drag for a dragon to be more agile. But that would take up a massive amount of magic energy, whereas, if you consider the possibility of using those magics on the fighter itself... a fighter plane with reduced air resistance, piloted by a dragon that can withstand several times the Gs of a human...

Comment: @Enthus3d aren't winged animals pretty agile? Like hawks for example. Though I have no real idea how that compares to fighter jets TBH

Comment: Then again, I'm referring to a single scene from a manga which made the dragon being more agile look good enough, in Gate: Where the JSDF Fought.

Comment: @JanDorniak in terms of speeds, birds can only reach a top speed of 200 km/h, by making use of gravity to dive. Compare this to a jet plane which can hit 3000+km/h. I am not sure about the agility of such birds, but compared to a jet plane, birds are not as capable of handling those kinds of G-forces (and don't really need to). Fighter planes are actually purposefully engineered to be highly unstable in flight, meaning that they are capable of quickly changing their flight paths to perform maneuvers.

Comment: @Enthus3d true that. Isn't the F117 impossible to fly without computer aides?

Comment: @JanDorniak but we are talking about dragons, rather than birds. Birds can't use magic to make themselves faster and maneuver better, but dragons absolutely can. That magic is what makes dragons the most versatile in almost any story, so it makes sense to assume dragons can perform rather well.

Comment: @Enthus3d yes, but you introduced the premise of the dragon saving it's magic, that's where my comparison is coming from.

Comment: @JanDorniak Yeah, but I mean that the dragon needs to use its magic to perform at a similar level to a jet plane, but, what if it uses its magic on the plane instead? It would save the magic it needed to reduce drag and what not, massively reducing the needed amount.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104839/discussion-between-enthus3d-and-jan-dorniak).

Answer (score 11):

Convenience and speed.

Unless your dragon has some magical powers helping it along, there is no way she ever could achieve the same speeds as a fighter plane.

Also, who doesn't prefer driving a car over walking? If it can be easier, then why not use the possibility?

Now how she will afford the fuel is another question. We all know how stingy dragons can be about parting with their hoard.

Comment: This. Why walk when you can drive the (heavily armed) sports car?

Comment: Imagine a medieval army’s surprise when they see their worst foe within their other worst foe...

Comment: If the powerful dragon is still able to use their magic on top of flying a fighter jet... Safe to say I wouldn't like to have them against me, now or in medieval times.

Comment: "Why walk when you can drive" : Because walking is safer

Comment: Actually, *lots* of people choose to walk at times. Walking is a *different* experience from driving. Some people just enjoy the physical exertion, it's less mentally taxing, and much more "tactile" than being in an enclosed vehicle.

Comment: @Matthew: If you include running & cross-country skiing as forms of walking, over the course of a year I probably spend more time walking than driving.  Indeed, a lot of my driving is just to get me to interesting places to go for a walk :-)  (And if you count the time when my horse is doing the walking, it's considerably more.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the best reason is that she can't fly properly anymore for some reason, and flying an airplane is the closest she can get. Maybe she has something like a torn wing that didn't heal properly, so she can't fly very well naturally anymore. If she were injured helping someone from the secret civilization, this could be why she was given an airplane in the first place.